# Extension language for Android app

Tags: android

I'm writing a Android app for encrypting texts, and I wonder if I can use a extension language to write additional algorithms outside the app instead of writing them inside the app and recompile the source. After doing some researches, Lisp seems to be a good language to use, and I've come up with a few choices:

1. **Write my own lisp.** This seems to be viable, but I always have trouble with writing a new program, and debugging is very time-consuming. It won't be my first choice.
2. **Use lisp written by others.** I've been searching Java-lisp repos on Github, and I found some small projects that may be useful, but lack some important features I want to include. I *can* add more to others' projects and use, but because of the reason above, this is not a good choice either.
3. **Use Clojure.** This seems to be a good choice, because [Clojure](http://clojure.org) is a well maintained and supported language. The only problem left is how to integrate it into my app.

Number 3 is my preferred choice now, but I want to ask you to help me choose. Other solutions are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Everyone is going to have their pet extension language (give me any Scheme, or Lisp over python, for example), but I really wonder is there anything that is proven to work well on android VMs. I think there are a lot of Lua based game projects, but that always felt too specific to the problem at hand.

Comment: @MaliRemorker I don't quite understand what you mean "work well." I just want a interpreter that can interpret scripts. I can just give it input and use the output.

Comment: Work well: "efficient and memory-friendly"

Comment: Well, in a JVM it seems like it's hard to be really "efficient and memory-friendly", but I think I'll just find a good and balanced (between efficiency and work) solution.